# can't connect localhost:3000 ruby on rails in vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I tried to connect localhost:3000 in windows

rails server is running in vagrant(ubuntu 14.10)

portforwarding is done

when, I tried 
`lynx 127.0.0.1:3000` in ubunutu, it works

but, in windows, I can't connect localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000 too

just showed ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

in cmd, I ran `netstat -t` result is :3000 TIME_WAIT

how can I solve this problem?

this is my 'Vagrantfile'

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu 14.10"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: "3000", host: "3000"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get install apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

edit: 
I tried to Host-only network adapter and I tried to connect 192.168.33.10:3000 in host machine
still can't connect. One weird thing, I can send Ping to 192.168.33.10 in host machine and reply was came. I don't know what the problem is. I confused. somebody help me, please :(

Comment: are you trying to connect to your rails application running in your ubuntu from your windows environment? if so they are not the same localhost...determine the ip of your ubuntu on the network

Comment: @LoganMurphy In some webpages for vagrant, I saw vagrant portforward in automatic. and I insert line `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000` in Vagrantfile

Comment: @LoganMurphy but I can ssh connect to ubuntu `localhost:2222`. if it possible, I think `localhost:3000` can reacheable too.

Comment: you need set port forward in Vagrantfile. Show us your `Vagrantfile`

Comment: @BMW I added my 'Vagrantfile', please check it, thank you

Comment: someone recommended that uncomment `# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"` . So I did it, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The solution is running the code below to start your server:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

I found this solution from another post about same problem.
The answerer said 'You'll want to make sure that the server is binded to 0.0.0.0 so that all interfaces can access it."

I hope this post helps people who encounter the same problem :)

Comment: It actually should be `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, "b" stands for "bind"

Comment: Works also with Thin. Thanks

Comment: What a surprise... I always thought that `rails server` listens on all interfaces by default unless specified. There is a good answer showing how to achieve this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server/29562898#29562898

Answer (score 24):

You can find the reason in here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html

> Due to a change in Rack, rails server now listens on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 by default

If you want to use `rails s` instead of `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, you can edit `/config/boot.rb`:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])

require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  class Server
    alias :default_options_alias :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_alias.merge!(:Host => '0.0.0.0')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: shilovk's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799260/ is a little better as it accounts for environment

Answer (score 1):

Also I have done something like this so that Guard starts this way:

  `guard 'rails', force_run: true, host: '0.0.0.0' do
    watch('Gemfile.lock')
    watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})
  end`