# Rails Webrick server default IP and port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, default, webrick

Rails -v 4.1.1
Ruby -v 2.2.1

I have 2 rails applications on one AWS EC2 instance. One app, I am able to startup on Webrick with:

```
rails server
```

I am then able to access the application remotely at the following URL:

```
 http://[public_ip]:3000
```

The second app, I have to provide the -b and -p options. Without the options accessing the application at `http://[public_ip]:3000` gives me:

```
This webpage is not available
connection attempt to [public_ip] was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

The only server startup otions that works for the second app is:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

I am then able to access the second app at `http://[public_ip]:3000`. The second app is a brand new app I created on the server. The first app is code I checked out from an existing app.
How do I make the second app behave the same as the first app?

Answer (score 0):

Before Rails 4.2 default binding host for `rails s` command was `0.0.0.0`. Starting from Rails 4.2 it's `localhost`. So it's no wonder you having this issue with the new app.

If you want your new app to start on `0.0.0.0` automatically, include this into `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
    end
  end
end
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562898/1426097).

Comment: I edited my post to show versions. Given that I'm working on a version before 4.2, server startup with no options should work. Also, the boot.rb for the first/existing app does not have the code snippet you provide yet I can access it on the default IP and port without the startup options.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.1/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L17 according to this in v4.1.1 default host is `0.0.0.0`. Are you sure Rails is 4.1.1?