# Rails Server: Unable to access application via private ip instead of localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, web

I start a Rails application and access http://127.0.0.1:3000 it works, but if i access http://192.168.0.59:3000 it's not.
My Mac's ip address is **192.168.0.59**

I think it works before. I want to use my iPhone to access my mac as a local server in a same intern network. Any hint?

EDIT:
Yeah, it's because rails server bind `127.0.0.1` so only my own machine can assess, so `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`.
Because i used shotgun so `shotgun -o 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check if the Rails server is bound to that IP address i.e. listening to incoming calls from there.

You can probably find your answer here: [How to change the default binding ip of Rails 4.2 development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server)

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 5:

```
$ rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```