# How to binding an external host for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, web-deployment

I deployed my ruby on rails project on a different virtual instance, and I changed the binding IP to an external floating IP by append this code to /config/boot.rb:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge(Host:  '199.116.235.154', Port: 3000)
    end
  end
end
```

and it can also be find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server). However, when I start the server by: `rails s`, I got this error:

```
> /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:240:in
> `initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for
> "199.116.235.154" port 3000
```

I know it is because 199.116.235.154 was an external host, so puma won't grant the access for me. And when I change it to internal IP: 10.2.3.52, it runs, but I can't target 10.2.3.52 from my phone browser or other computer.
So, is there any way for me to make the public 199.116.235.154 IP work for me?

Also, my frontend was built in a different directory by ember. They communicate with each end through jsonAPI, and currently I'm using localhost for debugging purpose:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  // Connect to Rails server
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
});
```

If I can make 199.116.235.154 host for my ruby on rails backend, will it also work for my ember frontend by changing localhost to 199.115.235.154?

Comment: Can you just bind to all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`? This will let the server be accessible on local and external IP addresses.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using proxy. it's easily setting up on Nginx:

Just install nginx and find the configuration file for it (normally it is located in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
and add following block:

```
 server {
   ...
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
   ...
```

and then you can access your backend rails app via http://public-ip/, suppose your nginx is running on regular 80 port.

Comment: I tried the same thing, but I can't target the public-ip.

Comment: when you set up nginx, could you access your default nginx index page by public ip?

Comment: I can access the default nginx index page, but I can't access my project page.

Comment: I'm using an instance similar to aws ec2. And I installed my app in /var/www/html

Comment: if you can access that default page through public ip, then the proxy setting should route the request to your 3000 port in the same host.
Did you check log of nginx?

Comment: Where can I find the log file?

Comment: you can find it in /var/log/nginx/ directory on most of systems.

Comment: I got `2016/03/28 23:56:22 [warn] 10459#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

Comment: if you can provide the whole config file, that would be more helpful.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed my problem without nGinx, I forced my app to run on port 3000, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Precompile your ember assets in rails: [ember-cli-rails](http://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails)
2. Deploy your app in heroku docker: [Deploy rails app in heroku docker](https://blog.codeship.com/deploying-docker-rails-app/)

The good thing for docker is it provide you pretty clear and accurate solution in the console when you got an error when build/run the docker machine.