# Rails Font CORS policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't load this font for a CORS Policy.

**Folder**: `app/assets/fonts/Inter-UI.var.woff2`

```
<%=preload_link_tag("Inter-UI.var.woff2", as:'font', crossorigin: "anonymous")%>
```

Error:

> Access to font at
>   'http://localhost:3000/assets/Inter-UI.var-e2e323d19d24946c4d481135af27ba00f3266aa9d4abe4262e97088feccb6ca4.woff2'
>   from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Response HTTP status code**

[image]

If I go directly to http://localhost:3000/assets/Inter-UI.var-e2e323d19d24946c4d481135af27ba00f3266aa9d4abe4262e97088feccb6ca4.woff2 I can download the file successfully.

I have already tried with [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), but it's not working

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
    end
  end
```

**application.rb**

```
 config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf|woff2)$/
```

**assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

CSS

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter UI';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
  src: font-url("/assets/fonts/Inter-UI.var.woff2") format("woff2-variations"), font-url("/assets/fonts/Inter-UI-Italic.woff2") format("woff2"), font-url("/assets/fonts/Inter-UI-Italic.woff") format("woff"); }
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? What happens if you paste `http://localhost:3000/assets/Inter-UI.var-e2e323d19d24946c4d481135af27ba00f3266aa9d4abe4262e97088feccb6ca4.woff2` into your browser address bar and try to open it directly in the browser?

Comment: It just says "(failed) net::ERR_FAILED" (added screenshot). If I go directly to font file URL it downloads it successfully.

Comment: Do you use `0.0.0.0` in any form to open your site in browser or start Rails server?

Comment: I don’t know if I undertstood what you meant. I start my server using “rails s” and it gives me the address 0.0.0.0:3000. Every url is generated by rails

Comment: Can you make sure this is the first middleware that gets installed?

Comment: It says "config.middleware.insert_before 0" so I guess so. How can I be 100% sure?

Comment: this happens when CORS request is sent to a server that doesn't set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response, in this case, request fails. Specifically, the browser disallows the request. Even if the server returns a successful response, the browser does not make the response available to the client application, hope this could help :)

Comment: can you run `rails server --binding localhost --port 3000`?

Comment: maybe this can help you bind your local host server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to `application.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf|woff2)$/
```

and update

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
    end
  end
end
```

with

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
    end
  end

  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "/assets/*", methods: :get,  headers: :any
   end
end
```

and you can simply use

```
<%= preload_link_tag("Inter-UI.var.woff2") %>



@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter UI';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
  src: font_url("Inter-UI.var.woff2") format("woff2-variations"), 
       font_url("Inter-UI-Italic.woff2") format("woff2"), 
       font_url("Inter-UI-Italic.woff") format("woff"); 
 }
```

and if you are using `fonts.css.erb` inside the `stylesheets` do

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Inter UI';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-display: swap;
      unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
      src: url(<%= asset_path "Inter-UI.var.woff2" %>) format("woff2-variations"), 
           url(<%= asset_path "Inter-UI-Italic.woff2" %>) format("woff2"), 
           url(<%= asset_path "Inter-UI-Italic.woff" %>) format("woff"); 
     }
```

and do `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Thank you. It's already present. Even with the "woff2" at the end.

Comment: Ok, I don't get the error anymore. But not loaded by CSS

Comment: Done, but nothing changed. No errors showed, the font it's not displayed. I don't know.

Comment: It is due to the fact that font location is not correct. Will you test with the new one