# How to pass the first index of the array to ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which has two input fields. One of them which allows white spaces gets value from the user. The second hidden input passes all data from the first input with removing all-white spaces.

I would like to send the second input's data to the ajax request as it doesn't have any white spaces. After that, I would like to control this data with API.

In ajax request, when I use `data: $('#firstInput').serialize(),` API returns null, if the user wants to use white spaces in the input.

When I use `JSON.stringify()`, I get a cross-origin frame error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost.dev" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` etc. doesn't work. To be able to overcome this problem, after some researches, I decided to use `param()` and `split()` functions. In this way, I get the result I want in `console.log()`.

How can I send the last split object to the ajax request in the data field?

```
var firstInput = $('#firstInput').val();
var trimInput = firstInput.replace(/\s+/g, '');
var hiddenInput = $('#hiddenInput').val(trimInput);

var paramFunc = jQuery.param(hiddenInput);
var splitFunc = paramFunc.split("=");
var result = splitFunc[1];

$.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: JSON.stringify(hiddenInput), //Gives: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost.dev" from accessing a cross-origin frame error
                            data: {"data": result}, // It returns null
                            success: function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: are you sure that `result` is not null ?

Comment: not sure why JSON.stringify would cause that error...That error has to do with the url you are posting too, not the data.

Comment: Yes, I am sure when I console.log before the ajax request, it gets values from the input. @DevsiOdedra

Comment: Seems like a strange setup for managing the data. Provide a [mcve]. Also what is expected format server side?

Comment: this is a security check, you are trying to access different domain, do you? it could be missing crossdomain attribute. and you can try to call serialize function on form element instead of input value

Comment: Actually, I make a request from an API service to control the data with the post method. I define the related API controller in the route file. And I call my defined localhost route in the ajax URL. My framework is Laravel, I also defined `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` in headers. Is it because I send a request in controller for an API service? @Lety

Comment: X.CSRF-TOKEN is used to prevent user’s web browser to perform an unwanted action on a trusted site when the user is authenticated, in your case the error suggest that you are sending an ajax request to a different origin, this is normally forbidden unless you configure your server to accept it and tell to your browser that your request is a cross site request. Sorry, but I don't know Laravel. You can read this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Test_Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing_(OTG-CLIENT-007) to understand CORS request and see if it is your case.

Comment: ma be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960709/rails-font-cors-policy could help